# Non-blocking code execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, meteor

I have a Meteor project that defines certain methods. In those, email is sent. Since that takes noticeable time and slows down the whole thing for end user, I'd like to send the email asynchronously. Whether the email was sent successfully or not has no effect on result of the method call.

From what I've found it's common to simulate async calls using `setTimeout`. Is that what I should be doing in this case too?

**EDIT:** Code as requested in comments

```
export const UpdateMaterial = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: 'material.update',
    validate: new SimpleSchema({
        id: {type: String},
        description: {type: String},
    }).validator(),
    run({id, description}){
        const _id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(id);

        let res;
        if(Meteor.isServer) {
            res = Materials.update({_id}, {
                $set: {
                    'metadata.description': description
                }
            });
         }
        SendHTMLEmailToRoles(Titles.NewMaterial,Texts.NewMaterial, [Roles.Admin]);
        return res;
    }
});

export const SendHTMLEmailToRoles = (subject,html,roles) => {
    if(Meteor.isServer) {
        const users = Meteor.users.find({role: {$in: roles}}).fetch();
        const addresses =  users.map(function(user){
            if(!user.emails)
                return;
            return user.emails.pop().address;
        });
        Email.send({
            to: addresses,
            from: 'test@test.com',
            subject,
            html
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html

Comment: @epascarello editted the question

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I know how to send an email, the async part is the problem

Comment: Well, the doc there says "send email asynchronously".

Comment: The only effect of the unblock function is allowing the client to make other calls, but it won't affect the method execution itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, the entire code that you show is a Meteor method?

In that case, calling it does not block the client at all, as all Meteor calls are asynchronous. That is why you can provide a callback.

However, the Meteor method on the server is synchronous if not carefully designed. So if the client makes further calls, they will not be processed until the email is actually sent.

To restore some asynchronous behaviour on the server for sending emails, pay attention to the `this.unblock()` line in the example of the reference page provided by Sergio (https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html)

Now if you want your Meteor call client callback to be executed right away, without waiting for the `Email.send()` to complete, you would have to delay that instruction (typically by wrapping it with a `setTimeout` indeed) to let your Meteor method returning.

Comment: Yea others methods being accessible (by calling this.unblock()) wasn't my concern and all I needed was the callback to be executed right away. Does the delay I pass to the function matter?

Comment: The delay (in ms) depends on what you would like your server to do before actually calling your `Email.send()` instruction. Most of the time `0` is enough, as you just want your instruction to be pushed at the end of the process queue, so that other pending tasks (including the rest of your Meteor method) can be executed before.

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know there was an option to just push the execution at the end.

Comment: Well that is actually how JS manages calls: they are just pushed on a queue. `setTimeout` simply pushes a new task after the given delay, but the task will actually be executed only once the previous tasks on the queue are processed.

Comment: Does that mean the delay is rather "minimal guaranteed delay" as if a long task starts being executed after calling timeout and before the timeout pushes the timeouted task to the queue, the timeouted task will be executed after the running one finishes?

Comment: Exactly. You can even imagine like calling 10 times `setTimeout(callback, 100)` in a row, and if each `callback` takes 10ms processing time, the 10th will actually be executed at least 190ms after you called the first `setTimeout`, whereas you specified a 100ms delay.